# Getitng a Twig Lang value dynamically

Tags: dynamic, twig, lang

I have a question about how I can pull a deep nested translation value from Twig dynamically.

Here is the setup:

I have my translations files in yml format (en.yml), here is an example:

```
parent:   
   child:
    something: here is some test
    another: more text here
```

I then have an array passed to Twig:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "GS"
    ["folders"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(3) "something"
        }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "I"
    ["folders"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(2) "another"
        }
    }
```

In twig, I want to print the folder names to screen, e.g.

`here is some test`

It would be easy if the lang file had everything in its root, I could use:

`{{ array.folders.name|trans }}`

However as this is a nested value in the lang file I somehow need to say:

`{{'parent.child'.array.folders.name|trans }}`

Any help would be very much appricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply first concatenate the string, then pass the value to the translator filter as follow:

```
{{ ('parent.child.' ~ array.folders.name)|trans }}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Damn, the round brackets are the secret. Thanks! :)